# Height of div not being applied to container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

So I am new to bootstrap 4 and sass and i want to do a project with both of them for the first time. The problem comes when I am trying to construct a div that is 900px in height but somehow, for some reason, it does not show up. It only shows up when I actually put things in it. What am I doing wrong here?

Could it be a problem because i am using sass? Or is it something completely else?

Code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.I {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

.II {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/94fb0667afbd3be221b09eb507991a22/tumblr_pwp1fg971T1qjb5z3o2_1280.png);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.II .nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.II a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.II a:hover {
  color: #cacaca;
}

.IV {
  background-color: #6362a7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.fa-suitcase {
  color: #f5b944;
}

.col-md-2 {
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 15%;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=webwavers.css.map */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="I container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="II container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">COSMOS</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto offset-1">
              <li class="nav-item offset-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item offset-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item offset-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- <div class="III container"> -->

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="IV container-fluid">
        <!--im small and i should be 900 px in height-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are using rows, but no columns. Read the bullet points in the Bootstrap docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works). _In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows._. I would start there

Comment: I tried doing that. Still not working. I tried doing this and it still doesnt give me the height i want. <div class="row">
      <div class="IV col-md-12">
       <div class="row">
        content
       </div>
       
       
      </div> 
     </div>

Comment: @moon, `.row > .col-*-12 > .row > (content)` is ***wrong***. Don't put content into `.row`. Put it into `.col-*-*`. i.e: `.row > .col-*-* > (content)` or `.row > .col-*-* > .row > .col-*-* > (content)` or `.row > .col-*-* > .row > .col-*-* > .row > .col-*-* > (content)`, etc...

Comment: @moonhowl You can accept whatever answer you found best...

Answer (score 1):

A simple `.container-fluid > .row > .col-12` will do. Giving `.col-12` (or any of its children) a `height` of `900px` will make it apply. Working example:

```css
.min-900 {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">COSMOS</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto offset-1">
      <li class="nav-item offset-2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item offset-2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item offset-2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 min-900"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

If you want to use `min-height` instead of `height`, your selector has to have a specificity of more than 1 class, because `.col-*` classes have a `min-height` of `1px`, which you need to override. Example:

```css
div.min-900 {
  border: 3px solid red;
  min-height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">COSMOS</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto offset-1">
      <li class="nav-item offset-2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item offset-2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item offset-2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 min-900"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, do not put content directly into `row`. You actually need to put it into `col-*-*` so what you need is to change that to `.row > col-*-* > (content)`. What I am using is simple notation. `<div class="warning><p class="bold">content</p></p>` corresponds to `warning > bold > (content)`. I think you'll understand what I am telling you by now.

Hope this helps!